# Draw a tiled cube of any size

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Draw a tiled cube of any size, in ASCII art.

You will be given three numbers `a`, `b` and `c`, and the program should output an a*b*c sized cube.

**Examples**

`3 3 3` ->

```
    ____ ____ ____
  /____/____/____/|
 /____/____/____/||
/____/____/____/|||
|____|____|____|||/
|____|____|____||/
|____|____|____|/
```

`5 2 3` ->

```
    ____ ____ ____ ____ ____
  /____/____/____/____/____/|
 /____/____/____/____/____/||
/____/____/____/____/____/||/
|____|____|____|____|____||/
|____|____|____|____|____|/
```

`4 6 5` ->

```
      ____ ____ ____ ____ 
    /____/____/____/____/|
   /____/____/____/____/||
  /____/____/____/____/|||
 /____/____/____/____/||||
/____/____/____/____/|||||
|____|____|____|____||||||
|____|____|____|____|||||/
|____|____|____|____||||/
|____|____|____|____|||/
|____|____|____|____||/
|____|____|____|____|/
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: I think it would look slightly better if the bottom-right piece was `/` instead of `|` so it matches the top, and the number of pipes in each vertical line be identical.

Comment: Also, what are the valid ranges for `a`, `b`, and `c`?  For example, are any of the dimensions allowed to be `0`?

Comment: @stevether: I didn't think about "tiled cube", that's a better name.

Comment: @mellamokb: a>0,b>0,c>0. It probably would look better, let me change that.

Comment: A cube has equal edges. Better to call it a tiled parallelepiped or brick.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: Generally, a cube is an a-by-b-by-c block, when talking about tiled cubes.

Comment: @beary605  I'm not a mathematician, but I think you may be referring to a rectangular cuboid. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid) A cube, a particular type of rectangular cuboid, has square faces. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) As far as I know, the name of the shape of the object doesn't change when the object is tiled.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: In the cubing community, cuboids are generally referred to as cubes (or a-by-b-by-c, which is a little more awkward), which is why I use the term.

Comment: @beary605 Ok. I wasn't aware of that. What's a cubing community, anyway?

Comment: @DavidCarraher: The people who speedsolve cube-styled puzzles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Python, 145 chars

```
a,b,c=map(int,raw_input().split())
for i in range(b+c+1):print(' '*(c-i)+((' /|'[(i>c)+(i>0)]+'_'*4)*(a+1))[:-4]+('|'*(b+c-i))[:b]+'/')[:5*a+c+1]

$ echo "5 6 3" | ./cube.py
    ____ ____ ____ ____ ____
  /____/____/____/____/____/|
 /____/____/____/____/____/||
/____/____/____/____/____/|||
|____|____|____|____|____||||
|____|____|____|____|____||||
|____|____|____|____|____||||
|____|____|____|____|____|||/
|____|____|____|____|____||/
|____|____|____|____|____|/
```

Comment: Could we see a picture of the printout?

Comment: @DavidCarraher: done.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <strike>148 143</strike> 139 chars

I decided to use transparent glass tiles.

The following code prints ASCII characters "-" in the form of a cuboid with edges, a, b, and c. The only thing you see in the figure below are hyphens.

```
w_~e~_ := {Arrowheads@Table[{1, p/9, Graphics@Style[Text["-"], Red]}, {p, 9}], White,Arrow@w};
GridGraph[{a, b, c} + 1, VertexSize -> 0, EdgeShapeFunction -> e]
```

[image]

Comment: That's not ascii... cool idea, but no.

Comment: It was admittedly cheeky on my part. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

### C, <strike>226</strike>, 212

```
s(x,y){x<1?:putchar(" |/_\n"[y],s(x-1,y));}i,j,x,y,z;main(){for(scanf("%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z);j<=y+z;s(i,1),s(j++>y,2),s(1,4)){s(z-j,0);for(i=x;s(1,j?j>z?1:2:0),i;i--)s(4,3);i=y+z-j;if(i>j)i=j;if(i>z)i=z;if(i>y)i=y;}}
```

Once again a poor score compared to other langs - so any C golf gurus able to improve?

Answer (score 1):

### Python3 (188)

```
a,b,c=map(int,input().split())
x=a+1
k="_"*4
p=print
l=5*a+c+1
p(" "*c+k.join(" "*x))
r=" "*c+k.join("/"*x)+"|"*b+"/"
exec("r=r[1:];p(r[:l]);"*c+'b-=1;p((k.join("|"*x)+"|"*b+"/")[:l]);'*b)
```

It is beaten already, but idea could help someone-else.